# How does the list indexing for a numpy array work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a small snippet of code and I am trying to understand how you can use another numpy array as an index to another numpy array.

```
bmi = np.array([13,14,15,22])
light = np.array(bmi) < 21
print(bmi[light])
```

output: [13,14,15]

I understand that when working with numpy arrays things are done element-wise so my assumption for bmi[light] would be that it will only print the corresponding values in bmi which have a value of true in light.

Comment: I think you need to read up on `boolean-indexing` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 0):

If you would to print `light` you would get:

```
[ True  True  True False]
```

Which is a boolean mask.

Now when you used `print(bmi[light])` you got bmi filtered to True.

You could have inverted that mask using `~` to get `[22]` only:

```
print(bmi[~light])
```

Same as pointed in comments you can learn more about boolean masking [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).